# IRC/SE relay bot

Tags: discussion, chat

Being new to SE chat, I would like to hear opinions from others of any pros/cons of this [recent idea](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32002872#32002872) of adding an IRC relay bot.

Comment: Would you like the code?

Comment: @PyRulez Sure! I have never built anything like that before and like to learn how you did it

Comment: https://github.com/ChristopherKing42/StackExchange-IRC-relay
The bot is currently down, so if you want to run it until needmoney90 gets back, feel free. (You can even set up rooms for the other irc rooms like #monero-dev, if you want those rooms.)

Comment: Just keep in mind [issue 6](https://github.com/ChristopherKing42/StackExchange-IRC-relay/issues/6) when you are testing it.

Comment: Also, this was mostly a copy and paste job (because I was doing it quickly). The code is really short, and it links original sources.

Comment: @PyRulez Thank you!

Comment: Also see http://meta.monero.stackexchange.com/q/83/255

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if the questions remains relevant since this appears to have been completed, but I think it is a useful idea.