# What channels do we want the IRC/SE relay bot for?

Tags: discussion, chat

So [we have an IRC/SE relay bot](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/q/81/255) (code [here](https://github.com/ChristopherKing42/StackExchange-IRC-relay)). What irc channels do we want it for?

We would need to open up a chatroom for each irc channel we want to connect to.

(needmoney90 on irc currently runs the other relays, so we can either ask him to run it (he run it for a little bit at #monero-se), or just run it ourselves. I unfortunately can not run it, not having any kind of server.)

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer should depend on the amount of usage. Currently #monero may be fine but as usage grows then using #monero-se might make more sense.

SE chat can become useful to discuss SE questions but so far has received very limited usage.

Comment: It is now running on #monero.